# How can I trigger the fullscreen galleria plugin on page load

Tags: javascript, wordpress, fullscreen, galleria

I'd like to get the fullscreen galleria plugin for wordpress to trigger on page load. Is this possible. There is only one collection of imaged on the page, and I want the plugin to start the fullscreen gallery as soon as the page finished lading.

Plugin homepage: http://wordpress.org/plugins/fullscreen-galleria/

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to trigger it then you can do it inside `window.onload`

```
window.onload = function(){
   // the page has finished loading. So trigger it here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately, I'm unsure how to trigger it

Comment: @NaNuk, Unfortunately, it is the same here :(

Answer (score 0):

You could try triggering button to launch gallery, something like

```
$(document ).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but again, it's not how to make 'something' trigger, but the exact function call to make which I need help with. Requires someone to understand a little about the fullscreen galleria plugin specifically.